# How i can programmatically share some file in Sharepoint 2013 when i'm not an administrator?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have edit permission to some file in sharepoint 2013 and i want to share this file with someone. I use this code:

```
var item = rootList.GetItemById(itemId);
clientContext.Load(item);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var allRoles = GetAllRoleDefinitions(clientContext);
var roleToAssign = allRoles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == "Contribute");
var principal = clientContext.Web.SiteUsers.GetById(member.Id);
var roleAssignmentForUser = item.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipalId(member.Id);
roleAssignmentForUser.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleToAssign);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But it throws ServerUnauthorizedAccessException. I checked this in sharepoint site and this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this Powershell script. It will remove anonymous access restrictions. It might help even though your users are authenticated.

$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity http://[your sharepoint url]
$webApp.ClientCallableSettings.AnonymousRestrictedTypes.Remove([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList], "GetItems")
$webApp.Update()